# Quality loss when uploading image with Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, intervention

I'm uploading an image using the below commands to Amazon S3:

```
$image = Image::make($request->file('image'))->encode('jpg', 100);
$image = $image->fit(1440, 768);
$image->save('uploads/image.jpg');
$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
$s3->put('cdn/uploads/image.jpg', fopen('uploads/image.jpg', 'r+'), 'public');
```

Although quality is at 100, an image larger than 1440x768 is saved with a very poor quality.

Am I overseeing something here?

I also tried uploading the image one on one, like below and still losing quality. Very clearly seeing the JPG compression

```
$image = Image::make($request->file('image'));
$image->save('uploads/image.jpg');
$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
$s3->put('cdn/uploads/image.jpg', fopen('uploads/image.jpg', 'r+'), 'public');
```

Can it be that there is a global GD setting for compression??

Comment: And if you comment this line `$image = $image->fit(1440, 768);`

Comment: Best package for images http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel

Comment: @Hackerman Still the same. Even removed the encoding and still it loses quality

Comment: @Ilya I already use that Package

Comment: Your post was deleted Ilya. But I did try what you suggested, but without sucess